# Getting the name and location of selected file Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a program in which I have a button to get File Dialog like [image]

How can I select a file, get the file name and location, and save that to a string displayed in the ui.The signal`clicked()`, emitted from the button, is connected to the slot `fileSELECT()`.

```
........
 void MainThread::fileSELECT(){
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Select video"),"d:\\BMDvideos",tr("Video files (*.avi)"));

   }
```

so when I select an .avi file, how do I get its location in fileName displayed like

```
  d:\BMDvideo\videFile.avi
```

Answer (score 1):

so I thinks that I got it now. my first code was completly wrong.

```
 void MainThread::fileSelect(){
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Select video"),"d:\\BMDvideos",tr("Video files (*.avi)"));
QLabel *testLabel =   new QLabel(fileName);
BOX->addWidget(testLabel);

    }
```

I can see  now the path of the selected file

Answer (score 0):

To get the folder path, you can use `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory`, and to get the file-name use `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName`

Comment: That's actually two different dialogs, one is for folder selection, the other for files. To split a filename into dir and filename, use QFileInfo. (basename(), fileName())